# How to sort array as to get all the numbers that are the same to the beginning of the array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I am working on a program from a yahtzee and I am trying to get all the cases where different points are given to for example 3 of a kind, 4 or a kind etc.

For that purpose I thought of arranging the values of the player dice and verifying if the first x where equal and going from there. I tried doing a selection sort and bubble sort but couldnt get them to work as they cant decide what to do when the numbers are the same. Any ideas for me to get this working?

This is the code I have tried for that purpose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 5

void
switches(float *v, float *m)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *v;
    *v = *m;
    *m = temp;

}

void
selection(int size, int *v)
{

    int min, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (v[j] <= v[min])
                min = j;
        }

        if (min != i)
            switches(v[i], v[min]);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    int size = n;
    int v[n] = { 2, 1, 3, 3, 3 };
    int m[n] = { 1, 3, 4, 3, 3 };

    selection(n, v);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("The values for the array are:%d\n", v[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

This is a test code on another file as I havent tried it in the actual program.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: In `selection` you don't initialize `min`. Also, why not use the built-in `qsort()` ?

Comment: G0ld, `switches(float *v, float *m) { int temp; temp = *v; ...` implies code is not compiled with all warnings enabled.  Save time - enable all warnings.

Comment: and does qsort work with numbers that are equal in value? if so then I can give it a shot

Comment: @G0ld Yes, `qsort()` works with numbers  equal in value.  Yet that is really just the fist step.

Comment: `min` is _unitialized_ so doing `v[min]` is UB (undefined behavior). It could work, produce "funny" results, or segfault. You probably want: `int min = 0;`

Comment: I have tried sorting it using qsort() and it doesnt work properly, it sorts but it doesnt get the numbers equal in value together or at the start

Comment: @CraigEstey tried fixing but still doesnt work

Comment: After commenting, I thought just initially setting `min` to 0 was insufficient. Then, I looked at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort From the pseudocode there [which you should follow], I'd do: `for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) { min = i; ...`

Comment: Ok, but I just put some more thought into it and I dont think this way is a good one. After sorting the dice it would loose all the previous values and I would have to reorganize it back. I think I need to find a better alternative for this.

Comment: You could sort an "indirect" array of `int *` or have the sorted array be an array of _indexes_ into the original array.

Comment: I suspect your goal is to write code that identifies all the Yahtzee scoring categories that a roll of five dice qualifies for. (Or, technically, to identify the score the dice would yield in each category, since any dice may be used for any category but score 0 when they do not match the category’s criteria.) If so, I suggest you update your question to say that.

Comment: Selection Sort works by iteratively placing one more element in its sorted position. That is, the array can be considered to be in two partitions: sorted and unsorted. Initially the sorted partition has zero elements and the unsorted is all the elements. Each time through the outer loop the sorted partition grows by one element. Thus, `min` is the minimum element in the _unsorted_ partition, so it should start with value equal to `i`, where `i` is the size of the sorted partition.

Comment: Most `qsort` implementations fall back to insertion sort if the number of elements falls below the minimum. I suspect that this would near optimal for time as well as space for <= 5 elements.

Comment: L1 cache is more than large enough to hold about 100 64-bit integers, over which Insertion sort should blow anything else out of the water. (These days. Don’t forget to profile!)

Comment: @G0ld "I have tried sorting it using qsort() and it doesnt work properly" --> your code did not call `qsort()` correctly.  `qsort()` itself is fine.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me exactly what you want. Can you add a some sorting examples.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb in C is: When you hear "sort/sorting" and "array" in the same sentence, your first thought should be `qsort`. (*That's probably also why `qsort` has been mentioned in a number of comments*)

An essential part of `qsort` is the compare-function. The compare-function gets the value of 2 array elements (well, really a pointer to two array element) and solely from those values the compare-function needs to return 1 of the following 3 results:

1. A before B
2. B before A
3. Doesn't matter

In most cases it's possible to write such a compare-function and therefore possible to do the array sorting using `qsort`.

**However...** The sorting requested in the question is not solely based on the values of two elements. The requested sorting involves the frequency (aka number of occurrences) of each dice value in the whole array.

Since we can't know the frequency of a specific value solely from the value itself, we can't write the compare-function. We would need some extra information that isn't available. So...

The conclusion is: **We can't use** `qsort`

**Unless...** we are willing to "cheat"/"do nasty stuff"/"..."

If we are willing to do that, we can get the extra information into the compare-function by using a (dreaded) global variable (oh dear...).

It could look like the code below. The idea is to count the frequency of each dice value and store it in a global variable **before** calling `qsort`. Then the compare-function can access the global variable to retrieve frequency information.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


// Global variable :-(
int cnt[7];  // 7 elements but element at index zero won't be used
             // as dice values are 1, 2, ..., 6

#define CNT_ARRAY_SIZE (sizeof cnt / sizeof cnt[0])

#define DICES 5

void roll_dices(int n, int roll[])
{
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) roll[i] = rand() % (CNT_ARRAY_SIZE-1) + 1;
}

void print_dices(int n, int roll[])
{
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) printf("%d ", roll[i]);
}

int cmp(const void *pa, const void *pb)
{
  int a = *(int*)pa;
  int b = *(int*)pb;

  // if A more frequent than B, return -1
  if (cnt[a] > cnt[b]) return -1;

  // if B more frequent than A, return 1
  if (cnt[a] < cnt[b]) return 1;

  // if A greater than B, return -1
  if (a > b) return -1;

  // if B greater than A, return 1
  if (a < b) return 1;

  // Same frequency, same value, retun 0
  return 0;
}

void sort_dices(int n, int roll[])
{
  // Calculate frequency
  for (size_t i=0; i < CNT_ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) cnt[i] = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) ++cnt[roll[i]];

  // Call qsort
  qsort(roll, n, sizeof roll[0], cmp);
}

int main(void) {
  srand(time(NULL));

  int roll[DICES];

  for (int i=0; i < 20; ++i)
  {
    roll_dices(DICES, roll);
    print_dices(DICES, roll);
    printf("-> ");
    sort_dices(DICES, roll);
    print_dices(DICES, roll);
    puts("");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
4 5 2 2 4 -> 4 4 2 2 5 
5 5 6 1 4 -> 5 5 6 4 1 
4 6 1 6 6 -> 6 6 6 4 1 
5 2 6 1 3 -> 6 5 3 2 1 
2 5 4 1 2 -> 2 2 5 4 1 
3 2 4 3 4 -> 4 4 3 3 2 
3 6 2 5 6 -> 6 6 5 3 2 
3 3 2 3 1 -> 3 3 3 2 1 
3 4 4 3 2 -> 4 4 3 3 2 
4 6 1 1 4 -> 4 4 1 1 6 
3 2 6 4 2 -> 2 2 6 4 3 
1 4 1 3 1 -> 1 1 1 4 3 
5 5 4 4 1 -> 5 5 4 4 1 
1 1 1 6 1 -> 1 1 1 1 6 
5 2 4 3 3 -> 3 3 5 4 2 
3 4 2 3 4 -> 4 4 3 3 2 
3 4 4 2 1 -> 4 4 3 2 1 
3 1 5 4 3 -> 3 3 5 4 1 
3 2 5 4 5 -> 5 5 4 3 2 
6 5 3 4 4 -> 4 4 6 5 3
```

Note: The main problem with the global variable is that it won't work as is in a multi-thread application. For multi-thread apps some extra code will be required to make sure that two threads doesn't interfere by updating the same global variable at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

BTW, a basic Selection Sort:

```
void selection_sort_int( int * array, size_t n )
{
  // Each time through this loop the array is one element more sorted
  for (size_t sorted_index = 0;  sorted_index < n-1;  sorted_index++)
  {
    // SUV == “smallest unsorted value”’s index
    size_t suv_index = sorted_index;

    // Find the suv in the remaining (unsorted) array
    for (size_t index = suv_index;  index < n;  index++)
      if (array[index] < array[suv_index])
        suv_index = index;

    swap_int( array+sorted_index, array+suv_index );
  }
}
```

We can rewrite that to a much more concise:

```
void selection_sort_int( int * array, size_t n )
{
  while (n --> 1)
  {
    int * min_value = array;
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < n+1;  i++)
      if (array[i] < *min_value)
        min_value = array + i;
    swap_int( array++, min_value )
  }
}
```

If you want that to have the same kind of generic interface as `qsort()` we can do that too. (We’ll just need a generic helper function to swap elements.)

```
void memswap( void * a, void * b, size_t nbytes )
{
  if (a == b) return;
  unsigned char * x = a;
  unsigned char * y = b;
  while (nbytes--)
  {
    unsigned char c = *x;
    *x++ = *y;
    *y++ =  c;
  }
}

void selection_sort(
    void * array, size_t n, size_t element_size, 
    int (* compare)( const void *, const void * ) )
{
  char * bytes = array;
  while (n --> 1)
  {
    char * min_value = bytes;
    for (size_t i = 0;  i < n+1;  i++)
      if (compare( bytes + i * element_size, min_value ) < 0)
        min_value = bytes + i * element_size;
    memswap( bytes, min_value, element_size );
    bytes += element_size;
  }
}
```

We can use that on an integer array the usual way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare_ints( const void * a, const void * b )
{
  if (*(const int *)a < *(const int *)b) return -1;
  if (*(const int *)a > *(const int *)b) return  1;
  return 0;
}

#define sizeof_array(xs) (sizeof(xs)/sizeof(xs[0]))

int main(void)
{
  int xs[] = { 3, 4, 2, 7, 3, 6, 7, 1, 5 };

  selection_sort( xs, sizeof_array(xs), sizeof(xs[0]), &compare_ints );

  printf( "%d", xs[0] );
  for (size_t n = 1;  n < sizeof_array(xs);  n++)
    printf( " %d", xs[n] );
  printf( "\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

Some important points:

- Selection Sort is ***not*** a stable sort. (That “swap” function in there throws a wrench in that. If you need stable, use Insertion Sort or Merge Sort.)
- Selection Sort is rather *slow* compared to other sorts. You should be using `qsort()` anyway.

<sub>PS. I just typed this in off the top of my head. If I’ve made any mistakes, be sure to comment.</sub>

<sup>PPS. Okay, I think I fixed all the typos.</sup>

Comment: Haters gonna hate?